# What is a good data collection to represent a horse race?

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, collections

I have a race course object which is an ArrayList which takes in Horse objects. I chose ArrayList because it's easy to implement. However, the downside of using an ArrayList is I can't easily keep track of the positions of each horse without going expensively iterating through the collection. For example, if I want to find 2 horses which are within an X amount of distance to each other, I would have to iterate through `n^2` times.

Is there a better strategy to do this?

EDIT: A lot of requests to be specific on my race model, so I'll elaborate here.

The model is updated every iteration. So every horse has its own speed, acceleration, distance travelled etc. and every iteration through the collection updates these values. There is a requirement for if a horse is near another it will slow down, which I plan on doing by comparing their 'distance travelled' values.

Comment: You can find such pairs of horses by sorting their positions and iterating, which is `O(n log n)`.

Comment: be specific: 1. do you have to query and change the values randomly? or 2. do you (repeatedly) {update values then perform queries}? case 1. -> tree with remove and re-insert, case 2. -> array: repeat {update values, sort, perform queries}

Comment: there's also a third case: can the values (i.e. the race positions) jump randomly? or can they only move up and down? in this third case you want a scan list (which is a sorted array) and moving up or down is equal to swapping positions in the array.

Comment: according to your updated description the {update, sort, query}-solution should fit nicely

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you may add Horse objects to TreeSet Collection. You should implement a Comparable interface in Horse class and override compareTo() method, thus sorting horses by distance. Then you may use specific operations on treeSet like "higher()" that will return the first horse that is ran more than given one, etc. You can read more about this collection [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html). Also all operations are O(lgN) by time complexity.

Comment: The caveat here is that the TreeSet doesn't automatically re-sort itself if the properties of the values which affect sort order are changed after insertion.

Comment: Sure, but I'm not exactly sure what the case is. But you're right about that. But the object can be removed and added again in O(lgN) time.

Comment: But TreeSet doesn't allow duplicates. This way you can lost horses with same distance

Comment: Sure, but you can compare them on two criteria - for example horses with same distance can be compared by name, thus allowing horses with same distance in TreeSet.

Comment: @NikolayTomitov yes. TreeSet is a good choice, just remove and re-add when you change a horse's position.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I've edited my question a bit. The ranking isn't the big issue and I've thought of TreeSort to solve it, but if I want to search for all horses which are of X distance apart to each other, could I do that with TreeSort?

Answer (score 0):

If you maintain a sorted list on horse position updates, then you could determine all pairs of horses X distance apart in one scan, N time (tradeoff being keeping the list sorted, log(n) per update).

If you instead want all horses X distance from a given horse H. You can also keep a hash map of horse to array index and potentially avoid iterating the entire array.